# Can't play wma, wmv or 3gp files

Tags: vlc, wma, wmv

Since I installed ubuntu 14.04 I can no longer play wmv, wma or 3gp files with any player ( gxine - vlc - totem - etc.)

I have installed Ubuntu restricted extras and ffmpeg.

My friends, I found the solution, and the solution is remove all gstreamer packages, then reinstall it.

Comment: do you get any kind of error or what? did you try to play it with default rhythmbox?

Comment: I have this problem too, I can not play rmvb files with any media player, in ubuntu the error I got is http://postimg.org/image/48ul2doq3/

Comment: No error message just crash.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Xubuntu 14.04, too. Solution above didn't work for me. The only workaround I found was to play wmv files using mplayer from terminal (since skinned version fails to load).

Like `mplayer [filename]`

Hope it helps.

EDIT: found out, that XBMC can play wmv files as well.

Comment: XBMC worked for me thanks. I need a solution for rhythmbox and vlc.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

Deleting the `~/.gstreamer-0.10` solved the issue. You may need to logout and in again.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with `VLC` in `Ubuntu 14.04` . and solved the problem by:

1] install last `ubuntu-restricted-extras` -> `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

2] Then upgrade `vlc` -> `sudo apt-get upgrade vlc`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem too, after some search I found this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libv4l/+bug/1313309) for vlc. I have installed `SMPlayer` from software center, now I can play those video files without any problem. you can try it too, see if it solve the problem.