# How to play 3gp videos with sound?

Tags: 14.04, sound, video, totem

I have Ubuntu 14.04, videoplayer Totem, and when I play video in 3gp using this videoplayer or any other, I can't hear a sound! How to solve this problem??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't play wma, wmv or 3gp files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481896/cant-play-wma-wmv-or-3gp-files)

Comment: For clarification purposes, what video players and video file players have you tested this on?

Answer (score 1):

Try Using VLC. It plays 3gp videos great. Install it with this command in a terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/602807)

Comment: @techraf He suggested using VLC and that can be an answer!

Comment: OP clearly wrote "using this videoplayer **or any other**, i can't hear a sound". This is a request for a clarification hence should be a comment.

Comment: @techraf It was a suggestion given in a form of a question. The intended meaning was using VLC, in my humbile opinion of course.

Comment: @AnwarShah I really am confused with your comments (both with you assuming there is a need for them and their content). Question is similar to "I have a network problem, I can't ping anywhere" the reply is "Try to ping 192.168.1.1". Even if the reply solved the problem, until the question is amended, it is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The container format 3gp most commonly contains the following codecs (I have added links to samples for testing):

1. H.263 video and AAC audio

   ```
   wget http://www.andrews-corner.org/samples/test_aac.3gp
   ```
2. H.263 video and AMR audio

   ```
   wget http://www.andrews-corner.org/samples/test_amr.3gp
   ```

Other codecs are possible (notably H.264 video and different favours of AAC audio) but these are the most commonly seen. These 2 samples (which I created myself with FFmpeg) play with Totem under Trusty Tahr with the addition of some gstreamer plugins, these are *not present* on a default installation of Trusty:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

With these downloaded and installed both sound and video should be fine. See this on my own Trusty installation:

[image]

The sound is not great but certainly should be able to be heard...

Other good choices for playback if you are still not happy with Totem's efforts are vlc and SMplayer:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc smplayer
```

and these two great players also have no issues with these two 3gp files on my Trusty system...

**Notes:**

The sample files were created as follows, using the latest git revision of FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i "The Swan of Tuonela.mp4" -s qcif -vcodec h263 \
       -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 8000 -r 25 -ab 12200 test_aac.3gp
```

and then:

```
ffmpeg -i "The Swan of Tuonela.mp4" -s qcif -vcodec h263 \
       -acodec libopencore_amrnb -ac 1 -ar 8000 -r 25 -ab 12200 test_amr.3gp
```

Comment: I have installed both codecs, I can hear the sound in them, but when I play another videos, I still can't hear any sound. I tried to install VLS player, and suddenly terminal said that "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming."

Comment: @ubuntubeginner So the 2 sample files I have created play ok on Totem? I am wondering if perhaps your other 3gp files are at fault. Can you post one of the offending files here: https://www.datafilehost.com/